# What is trans-addition?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, terminology

A question from JEE-Advanced(2017) :
[image]

Bromination of both Z-but-2ene and E-but-2-ene involve syn and anti addition. So, there would be 4 products as suggested in the question. But, I don't understand the terminology of 'trans-addition', mentioned in the question.

What is actually trans addition?

Comment: Uh, I think that the correct term should be "anti" not "trans"

Comment: Why do you think there will be syn addition?

Comment: A screenshot or picture of written text is problematic as it cannot be indexed by our site search or other search engines. Chemistry.se is about the content, and your question is unlikely to be helpful in the future for other people. Please take a couple of minutes to transcribe the text, so that it can be found easily in the future.

Comment: @Martin Well, I am kinda underskilled at mhChem and with my mobile phone jt's hard to draw chemical structures. So, I am sorry. But I will edit the question.

Answer (score 6):

Just like @QuantumAMERICCINO has pointed out, it's probably *anti* addition.

Furthermore, you seem to wonder why a *syn* compound doesn't form. It all lies in the mechanism of bromination:

The double bond in *cis*-2-butene polarises the $\ce{Br-Br}$ bond in a nearby $\ce{Br2}$ molecule. A $\ce{Br+}$ ion attacks the double bond and forms a **bromonium ion**.

[image]

The bromonium ion makes the adjacent carbon atoms electrophilic. The bromide may attack the most electrophilic out of them. Here, however, they are equivalent.

[image]

You should now be able to understand how the mechanism works.

Comment: So how are there 4 products?

Comment: What 4 products @Mockingbird360

Comment: M,N,O,P as suggested in the question.

Comment: @Mockingbird360 Oh that, they are just stereoisomers. I showed in my example, the bromine attacking the left carbon. If it attacked the right one instead, you would get the enantiomer of the above compound. For a *trans*-2-butene you would get a *meso* product.